# Подскажите , как на selenium python очистить local storage

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

Подскажите , как на selenium python очистить local storage. Кнопка выхода на сайте заблокирована. Как правильно это сделать, начинаю только писать автотесты.

Comment: посмотрите попробуйте вот тут - https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/10466/how-to-clear-localstorage-using-selenium-and-webdriver

Comment: Спасибо большое